# C# async / await method to F#?

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I am trying to learn F# and am in the process of converting some C# code to F#.

I have the following C# method:

```
public async Task<Foo> GetFooAsync(byte[] content)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(content))
    {
        return await bar.GetFooAsync(stream);
    }
}
```

Where `bar` is some private field and `GetFooAsync` returns a `Task<Foo>`.

How does this translate to F#?

Here is what I currently have:

```
member public this.GetFooAsync (content : byte[]) = 
    use stream = new MemoryStream(content)
    this.bar.GetFooAsync(stream)
```

Which returns a `Task`.

Comment: What's the point of the `stream` variable here, or the `content` parameter? In both your C# and F# code, they don't seem to be used anywhere in your function.

Comment: Doh! My sample is a simplified version of the actual code but I accidentally omitted the use of the stream. Updated the question.

Comment: @OJRaqueño you don't need `await` if you don't intend to use the result of the asynchronous call. Just return the task itself, ie `return bar.GetFooAsync(stream);` In this case, you *have* to use it though because you are doing trying to do something on a memory stream that will be disposed - why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In F#, asynchrony is represented by the `async` computation builder, which is not an exact analog of `Task`, but can generally be used in place of one:

```
member public this.GetFooAsync (content : byte[]) = 
   async {
      use stream = new MemoryStream(content) 
      return! this.bar.GetFooAsync(stream) |> Async.AwaitTask
   } 
   |> Async.StartAsTask
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. On the `return` line, I'm getting an error: `This expression was expected to have type Async<'a> but here has type Task<Foo>`. The `GetFooAsync` method returns a `Task<Foo>`.

Comment: Indeed. The expression after `return!` must itself be an `Async<'t>`, but `GetFooAsync` returns a `Task<'t>`. Missed that detail. I have updated the code to convert using `Async.AwaitTask`.

Comment: Got it. Can you also share how it might change the calling code? The calling code is expecting the return value of this method to be of type `Task<'t>` instead of `Async<'t>`.

Comment: It's converted back to `Task` at the end via `Async.StartAsTask`.

Comment: Oh yes, that's right. Obviously I still have a lot to learn about F#. :)

Answer (score 6):

If you are converting `async`/`await`-intensive C# code to F#, it might get cumbersome because of the difference between F#'s `async` and `Task` and the fact that you always have to call `Async.AwaitTask`

To avoid that you can use FSharpx library, which has a `task` computation expression.

```
let tplAsyncMethod p = Task.Run (fun _ -> string p)

// awaiting TPL method inside async computation expression
let asyncResult = async {
                   let! value1 = tplAsyncMethod 1 |> Async.AwaitTask
                   let! value2 = tplAsyncMethod 2 |> Async.AwaitTask
                   return value1 + value2
                }

// The same logic using task computation expression
open FSharpx.Task
let taskResult = task {
                    let! value1 = tplAsyncMethod 1
                    let! value2 = tplAsyncMethod 2
                    return value1 + value2
                }
```

The result of `asyncResult` is `Async<string>` and the result of `taskResult` is `Task<string>`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip; I'll definitely check that library out.

Comment: Just noting that `task` computation expressions are built-in as of F# 6: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/whats-new/fsharp-6#task-