# asynchronous unit tests with ms test

Tags: f#, mstest

How to test the asynchronous methods in ms unit test leading to successful or failed unit tests

```
[<TestClass>]
type TestRequestDataClass () =

    [<TestMethod>]
    member this.TestRequestDataAsync() = async {
        let! result = requestDataAsync()
        match result with
        | Ok result ->   Assert.IsTrue(true)
        | Error error -> Debug.WriteLine(error)
                         Assert.IsTrue(false)
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem you're facing? What have you already tried to resolve it?

Comment: the problem is I can't see the unit tests in my IDE, the listing disappeared, do you see any problem with the syntax etc. for the unit test

Comment: there's something wrong with unit test having async body, it just disappears from the IDE

Comment: is there another way to call async methods without having to declare async body, so my ide can recognize unit tests

Comment: Does it detect non-async tests?

Comment: Test methods need to be public. I am not that familiar with f#, but you should make sure that the test method is public so that the test runner can discover it.

Comment: yes it's detecting non async tests

Comment: Take a look at how the async member is defined here and see if it applies to your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/40359903/5233410

Comment: Are both the test class and test method public?

Comment: I think it's not about access, as soon as I remove async block, test is visible, I add the block back in, it disappears, seems like a bug within rider

Comment: MSTest requires test methods to return either `void` or `Task<_>`. Your function returns an `Async<_>`, so MSTest ignores it. Make it return a `Task<_>`.

Comment: I added this line at the end, `|> Async.StartAsTask` will it return a `Task<_>`

Comment: @FyodorSoikin It is suppose to be `void` or `Task`, not `Task<_>`. Again I am not that much familiar with f# syntax

Comment: how do I return a Task, an empty task?

Comment: @Nkosi please add the line in c# and I'd work it out for f#

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I tried this answer of yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358820/c-sharp-async-await-method-to-f/40359903#40359903 but it didn't work for unit test in this case

Comment: @App2015 This is how the test method would look like in c#  `[TestClass] public class TestRequestDataClass { [TestMethod] public async Task TestRequestDataAsync() { ... } }`

Answer (score 2):

I don't have MS Test to try this, but if you need to produce a method that returns non-generic `Task` (as opposed to generic `Task<T>`), then you can define the following helper:

```
open System.Threading.Tasks

let startAsActionTask f = 
  Async.StartAsTask f :> Task
```

The `Async.StartAsTask` always creates a generic `Task<T>`, but aside from that, it is pretty much the same as this helper. Then you can use the helper as follows:

```
[<TestMethod>]
member this.TestRequestDataAsync() = startAsActionTask <| async {
    let! result = requestDataAsync()
    match result with
    | Ok result ->   Assert.IsTrue(true)
    | Error error -> Debug.WriteLine(error)
                     Assert.IsTrue(false)
}
```

Comment: error `this expression was expected to have type `unit->unit` but here has type 'Async<'a>'`. squiggly lines are at the word async

Comment: @App2015 You're right! My helper was wrong. Fixed now.

Comment: I tried your approach, error disappeared but the unit tests are not showing up, earlier I came up with a solution, I removed the async block and used `match (requestDataAsync() |> Async.RunSynchronously) with` and I could see unit test appearing in the list.

Comment: I came across your article http://tomasp.net/blog/csharp-async-gotchas.aspx and it helped me took this route.