# How to consume this EF Core C# async method in F#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, f#, async-await

I am using F# with Entity Framework and I can't get my head around consuming C# async methods from F#. Despite others SO answers related to similar issues can't really get my head around.

Here is my attempt with the code below, initially synchronous:

```ml
let getAirport (id: Guid) =
    use context = new MyContext()
    context.Flights.Find id
    |> (fun x -> if box x = null then None else Some x)
```

And its `async` counterpart:

```ml
let getAirportAsync (id: Guid) =
    async {
        use context = new MyContext()
        let! flight = context.Airports.FindAsync id |> Async.AwaitTask
        return (fun x -> if box x = null then None else Some x)
    }
```

However, when both are called in the main:

```ml
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let myGuid = Guid.NewGuid()
    let airport = {
        Id = myGuid
        Name = "Michelle"
        X = 42.0
        Y = 42.0
    }
    AirportRepository.addAirport airport
    let thisAirport = AirportRepository.getAirport myGuid
    let thisAirportToo = AirportRepository.getAirportAsync myGuid |> Async.RunSynchronously
    assert (thisAirport = Some airport)
    assert (thisAirportToo = Some airport)
    0
```

It cannot compile:

```
  Program.fs(61, 13): [FS0001] The type '('a -> 'a option)' does not support the 'equality' constraint because it is a function type
  Program.fs(61, 30): [FS0001] This expression was expected to have type    ''a -> 'a option'    but here has type    ''b option'
```

I read:

- https://medium.com/jettech/f-async-guide-eb3c8a2d180a
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/tutorials/asynchronous-and-concurrent-programming/async
- [C# async / await method to F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358820/c-sharp-async-await-method-to-f)

I thought the process to consume an `async` C# method was:

- Pass the C# method to `|> Async.AwaitTask`
- Pass the result to `let!`
- Return that result
- Wrap everything in an `async` block which forms the body of an `async` F# function
- Use that newly `async` created F# function by passing it to `|> Async.RunSynchronously`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in `getAirportAsync` you discard `flight` and just return the function. The fix is simple:

```
let getAirportAsync (id: Guid) =
    async {
        use context = new MyContext()
        let! flight = context.Airports.FindAsync id |> Async.AwaitTask
        return if box flight = null then None else Some flight
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, guess I was too sleepy!

Comment: Side note: That last line could just be `return Option.ofObj flight`.